# How to create submodule in GitHub using GitHub Rest Api

Tags: github-api

I found that GitHub has [Create Tree](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#create-a-tree) and [Create File](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file) API, but I am still not sure how to create the submodule item, for Create Tree Api, how to specify the Sha, for Create File Api, it seems we can't set item type. BTW, do I need to first create the .gitmodules file?

Comment: you should mention what've you tried. and if you google for your problem, you'll find the first result - https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was trying to do this earlier today.

Here's my workflow:

1. [Create a tree](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#create-a-tree)
2. [Create a commit](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#create-a-commit)
3. [Update the reference](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#update-a-reference)

**Let me give a little example to make it more clear.**

Say the latest commit on the `master` branch of the repo you want to add a submodule is `$BASE_SHA`.

---

**1. Create a tree**

Assuming you don't have any submodules on your repo yet, you'll need to create a file named `.gitmodules` first. And then you can create a reference to it.

```
POST /repos/:owner/:repo/git/trees
{
    "base_tree": $BASE_SHA,
    "tree": [
        // create submodule config
        {
            "path": ".gitmodules",
            "mode": "100644",
            "type": "blob",
            "content": "[submodule \"rails\"]\n\tpath = rails\n\turl = https://github.com/rails/rails"
        },
        // link to submodule
        {
            "path": "rails",
            "mode": "160000", 
            "type": "commit",
            "sha": "39e087cbf5628ecc351fc86a3a1e320be193bf29"
        }
    ]
}
```

The API server will then send a response to you

```
{
  "sha": $TREE_SHA,
  "url": "...",
  "tree": [...]
}
```

---

**2. Create a commit**

We then use the `sha` of the newly created tree to create a commit (with `$BASE_SHA` as its parent).

```
POST /repos/:owner/:repo/git/commits
{
    "message": "commit message",
    "tree": $TREE_SHA,
    "parents": [$BASE_SHA]
}
```

And the server will return

```
{
    "sha": $COMMIT_SHA,
    "url": "...",
    // other content omitted here ..
}
```

**3. Update the reference**

We then need to update the `master`.

```
PATCH /repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs/heads/master
{
    "sha": $COMMIT_SHA,
    "force": true
}
```

And we're all set if no error is returned.

Refresh your GitHub repo page and you'll find the submodule is added.

Comment: Thanks Cheng-Yu, great job. Only one thing I found maybe need to modify is the request method should be "POST" in creating a tree

Comment: Eagle eyes! Just updated my answer, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -2):

Note: this is now possible in GitLab as well, since 11.5 (Nov. 2018)

That Stack Overflow question was referenced in [gitlab-org/gitlab-ce issue 41213](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/41213#note_75396439).

> ### [Update Git submodules via API](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/11/22/gitlab-11-5-released/#update-git-submodules-via-api)
>
> Git submodules allow you to include a Git repository within another Git repository.
>
> GitLab now supports updating the submodule reference via the API.
> This is particularly useful for automation, allowing you to keep your project up to date with the latest dependencies using the API.

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_submodules.html).